# ThreadPool is to Executor like Polling is to?

Tags: java, polling, executor, gigaspaces

Java's Executor is (as far as I understand it) an abstraction over the ThreadPool concept - something that can accept and carry out (execute) tasks.

I'm looking for a similar exception for the Polling concept. I need to continuously poll (dequeue) items out of a specific Queue (which *does not implement* `BlockingQueue`), execute them and sleep, and repeat all this until shutdown.

Is there a ready-made abstraction or should I write something on my own?

(Suggestions of a better title are welcome)

Comment: Title suggestion: "How can I integrate a custom queue into the j.u.c executors?"

Comment: To me title is fine, I understood from your title what you were after. And it has a riddle-ish ring to it.

Comment: Well, one suggestion is to use Quartz ffs! I don't think the title is clear at all. Polling is a couple of lines of code (see my answer below), whereas a thread pool may be a thousand. Why would you need an abstraction layer for a few loc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling is easy:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!t.isInterrupted()) {
               Object item;
               while ((item = queue.take()) == null) {//does not block
                   synchronized (lock) { lock.wait(1000L) } //spin on a lock
               }
               //item is not null
               handle(item);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
});
t.start();
```

Perhaps you need to rephrase your question as I'm not quite sure exactly what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: My own queue is something custom (a GigaSpaces queue), it does not implement the BlockingQueue interface.

Comment: Then add a simple adapter which does implement the interface and delegates to your queue impl

Comment: I can't - GigaSpaces is a distributed grid - the push() operations to the queue are done on another computer. Ergo, what I need is actual polling - I don't see how I can implement BlockingQueue.

Comment: The queue's interface is write() and take() - and since the write() is happening on another computer (and my process might not even be up at that point), there's no operation I can take then.

What I need is a thread that keeps polling this queue (calling take()), with some minimal lifecycle management.

Comment: Does take() not block? (See my answer above). I still don't see why you can't write an adapter (it doesn't matter who is putting items on the queue as long as the take operation behaves as it should)

Comment: take() unfortunately doesn't block.

Comment: Correction - take() can block for a specific amount of time, but I guess my actual situation is more complicated than I described here - I'd like to takeMultiple(), and more...

I guess your answer answers my question as phrased.

Comment: See my modified answer - the polling is really easy and there's no need of a control abstraction. Please ignore the Quartz answer; Quartz has nothing whatsoever to do with your problem